# Version Info Table Changing pe file by UpdateResource?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, portable-executable

I'm running program correctly and I see Version Information but in the update resource api run and does not replace the compnayname.

```
LPCWSTR filename = _T("r1.exe");
size = GetFileVersionInfoSize(filename, &dwHandle);
std::vector<BYTE> fileInfo(size,0);
f = GetFileVersionInfo(filename, 0, size, &fileInfo[0]);
VerQueryValue(&fileInfo[0], TEXT("\\VarFileInfo\\Translation"), (LPVOID*)&pValueBuffer, &verLength);
SubBlock.Format(_T("\\StringFileInfo\\040904B0\\CompanyName"), "0x0409", "1200");
VerQueryValue(&fileInfo[0], SubBlock, (LPVOID *)&lpBuffer, &dwBytes);
ZeroMemory(lpBuffer, _tcslen(lpBuffer) * sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy(lpBuffer, _T("My Company"));
HANDLE hResource = BeginUpdateResource(filename, FALSE);
VerQueryValueW(&fileInfo[0], TEXT("\\VarFileInfo\\Translation"), (LPVOID*)&pValueBuffer, &verLength);
f=UpdateResource(hResource, RT_VERSION, MAKEINTRESOURCE(VS_VERSION_INFO), MAKELANGID(SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), &fileInfo[0], sizeof(lpBuffer));

EndUpdateResource(hResource, FALSE);
```

How can I Replace the Company name or other String Info Table Features????

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet does not do what you expect it to do.

`BeginUpdateResource`, `UpdateResource`, `EndUpdateResource` indeed do the update cycle and you use the API in a presumably correct order. However your `UpdateResource` uses the same original data block you read from the file.

`VerQueryValue` **extracts you the string and does not provide you with a method to update the value within the original block**.

If you want to update the resource, you are responsible for reading the entire `VERSIONINFO` resource, for parsing it out into parts, updating the string in question, assembling the resource back into a byte buffer and then using the `UpdateResource` API. There is no API, to my best knowledge that helps you with parsing and assembling the `VERSIONINFO` data end to end, you are responsible for taking care of this yourself following MSDN data structure (and it's doable).

Comment: Hi Roman  By definition update resource in MSDN :   Adds, deletes, or replaces a resource in a portable executable (PE) file. then possible change information in Resource Pe file but my code is not work.Thanks for  Answer

Comment: The API works well and as documented. It is you who do not provide proper re-formatted data block for the update.

Answer (score 2):

The `GetFileVersionInfo[Size]` and `VerQueryValue` functions [abstract away](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603) some of the resource version layout details and cannot be used when you want to build resources. You can use them to read if you really want to but you have to manually create the full version resource in memory if you want to update it because 1) there are some alignment requirements and 2) it stores the string size in the string header.

[MSDN has decent documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468916(v=vs.85).aspx) that should help you to lay things out correctly in memory. It starts with `VS_VERSIONINFO` and `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` and the rest are not true C/C++ compatible structs but you can study other resources in a hex-editor to make sure you are doing it correctly.